# variable should not grow

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

i'm struggling for quite a long time with a strange problem in my javascript. 
this is what i do:

1. collecting some elements from the html code
2. change their order randomly and 'put them back'

i compute each position of the divs by getting their height and adding some offset. 
my variable 'topPos' is going crazy. everytime the function gets evaluated it does not
reset. instead it grows and grows. the site becomes quite glitchy in a nice way. but this 
time i just want it to work in the right way.. ( : 
can someone help? 
thanks.

here is the code:

```
function setPos(){
  var vidArray = shuffleFrames();
  var topPos = 30;
  var prevHeight = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < vidArray.length; i++){
    var element = vidArray[i];
    element.style.top = topPos.toString() + "px";
    prevHeight = $(vidArray[i]).height();
    topPos = topPos + prevHeight + 15;
    element.style.display = "block";  
  };
topPos = 30;
};
```

it gets called by this function:

```
function randStart(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("videofont");
  getElements(elem);
  setPos();
};
```

here is the html-part:

```
div id="p00" class="videofont" >
<iframe src="some video" ></iframe>  
</div>

div id="p01" class="videofont" >
<iframe src="some video" ></iframe>  
</div>

div id="p02" class="videofont" >
<iframe src="some video" ></iframe>  
</div>

" … and so on "
```

the remove function :

```
function remPos(){
  var vidArray = frames;
  for(var i=0; i<frames.length; i++){
    var element = vidArray[i];
    element.style.display = "none";
    $(element).removeAttr('style'); 
  };
};
```

the rest:

```
function shuffleFrames() {
  var currentIndex = frames.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = randomizer(currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = frames[currentIndex];
    frames[currentIndex] = frames[randomIndex];
    frames[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  };

  return frames;
};


var frames = [];
function getElements(elements){
  for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    frames.push(elements.item(i));
  };
};
```

the css for .videofont sais: 
    .videofont {
      position:absolute; 
      left:400px; 
      top:300px; 
      z-index:999; 
      display:none;
    }

thanks!

Comment: Does `videofont` include any kind of `margin`, `border` or `padding` styles?

Comment: And can you explain a bit more clearly what happens?

Comment: Could you show us the code of `shuffleFrames()` ? and what does the `getElements(elem);` do ?

Comment: what is vidArray? and are you using jquery? `$(vidArray[i]).height();` looks like a jQuery function yet you use pure js everywhere else

Comment: here's your above code in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9UU37/ If you can make the fiddle replicate your issue, we'll have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: thank you. i updated it. but i think it doesn't support <iframe>? anyway. maybe it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/9UU37/1/

Comment: Sub in a `<span>number</span>` for your `<iframe>` since the code does not depend on the element being an `<iframe>`

Comment: ah. ok. then there must be another mistake because the iframe element already has some content that should be displayed. but this problem  consists only ths jsfiddle thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9UU37/10/

Comment: something seems to get saved. but i cant imagen what it could be… the only variable in relation with the position is 'topPos' and this gets reseted every time before setPos() is called .

Comment: ok. you just forgot to clear the frames array. 
really strange things were going on there. 
but now. just add `frames = []`
to the remove function and everything works as it should.